# Images(align vertical) inside a flexbox container, doesn' change size, if the parent change size (using flexbox)

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm having a container split in two. In the left part I have text, and in the right part I have images.

The issue is that the image remain the same, doesn't shrink by flex or by using media queries.

```css
.container{   
display:flex;
   flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 40.25rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.place {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 160px;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20px;
}    

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.place {
flex-basis: 100px;
}
}
.place > * { 
flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.place > * img { 
max-width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </div>
  <div class="place">
    <a href=""> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href=""> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href=""> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: they shrink for me, I can see a slight shrink du to the flex-basis being reduced

Comment: @TemaniAfif, I changed the unit to pixels. 1) the image(img) is not going to max-width, is much smaller. 2) if I remove max-width from img no shrink happens

Answer (score 0):

Even though your question is not clear to me, seems that you are trying to set dimensions to *place*, and not getting what you expect for.

But the *place* has set the default value for flex-shrink: 1, and since the available space is reduced, *place* is being reduced to the available space.

I have changed this to *no-shrink* to whow that you are really able to set those dimensions

```css
.container{   
display:flex;
   flex-direction: row;
    max-width: 40.25rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.place {
    display: flex;
    flex-basis: 160px;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: 20px;
    flex-shrink: 0; /* added */
}    

@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {

.place {
flex-basis: 100px;
}
}
.place > * { 
flex: 0 1 100%;
}

.place > * img { 
max-width: 100%;

}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content">
  of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy. Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).
  </div>
  <div class="place">
    <a href=""> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href=""> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
    <a href=""> <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" /></a>
   </div>
 </div>
```